# How do I stop IIS7.5 starting by default?

Tags: windows, iis, windows-7, iis-7.5, service

I am doing a lot of work using the XAMPP stack, but every time I restart my machine, I have to manually stop IIS before I can start Apache.

I can't find a service for IIS to configure not to start automatically. How can I prevent IIS from starting automatically?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to disable two services:

- World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC)
- IIS Admin Service (IISADMIN)

Go to Services, properties of the above mentioned services, change the start up type to "Disabled"

Enjoy.

Comment: If you want to be able to run IIS, setting the start up type to "Manual" – and then use `iisreset` or a service control tool to start when required.

Comment: agree with Richard. you can update the type to manual so you still able to start, instead of disabling it.

Comment: Not seeing IISADMIN on Windows 2012 R2 Server

Comment: I had IISADMIN on Windows 2012 R2 Standard, so it should be there.

Comment: On Windows 10 (IIS10) none of them exists

Comment: @the_nuts the W3SVC exists on my Windows 10 Pro 21H1 Version....but the IISADMIN not...

Answer (score 7):

Look for World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC) in services.

Also you could change the default port into something that does not conflict with Apache?

Comment: +1 for the port idea. I'll do that when I'm back to using both servers.

Comment: how to change the port used by IIS

Answer (score 3):

1. Hit Windowskey-R (or click start -> run).
2. Type in "`services.msc`"
3. Double Click "`World Wide Web Publishing Service`" to view its properties
4. On the first tab "`General`" you'll see a "`Startup type`" drop down box, set it to "`Manual`" or "`Disabled`".

Comment: don't forget to also disable the admin service (see Noor's answer)